# login loop ubuntu?

Tags: login, 19.04

I stuck in the login loop ubuntu 18.10
and after I enter ctrl+alt+f3
I can not log in to my user account 'jake'
but I can log in to 'root'
then I can not see any xauthority in the file system.
what should I do with root to fix the login loop

Comment: 18.10 is past support here, you should be upgrading to a newer release of Ubuntu.

Comment: http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/07/19/ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-end-of-life-reached-on-july-18-2019/  (18.10 is EOL) & thus off-topic (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) as already stated